# Is there an API for Windows Live Mesh?

Tags: mesh

Is there an API for Windows Live Mesh?

Answer (score 2):

It's REST based (along with the rest of the Live suite), and you can get a somewhat interactive play with it @ http://rex.mslivelabs.com/

Mind, Live is transitioning to the 2011 release so things there may change.

Comment: That looks interesting but I didn't see anything about Mesh in it.

Comment: the Live API's were discontinued last year in preparation for the transition to Windows Live 2011's official release. If they've already taken it out of Rex, then it'll have been moved over to the Windows Messenger Connect, which are @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/default.aspx